# How to set the encoding format UTF8 for the XMLUnit API (org.custommonkey.xmlunit.XMLUnit)

Tags: java, xml, encoding, utf-8, xmlunit

I'm doing a XML comparison between 2 xml files. 
My xml files (to be compared) contains a UTF8 BOM (viz.., EF BB BF ) in it.
So, when I'm try to invoke the Diff API (of org.custommonkey.xmlunit.XMLUnit.Diff) with UTF8 encoding then I'm getting an exception like :

`org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Content is not allowed in prolog.`

Removing these 3 Hex values (EE, BB & BF) will resolve the problem, but I need a way to set the encoding UTF8, so that the XMLUnit API works even for a UTF8 encoding enabled XML file.

Suggestions are welcomed !

Comment: There is unfortunately no quick-fix for your problem. The accepted answer to the question I linked to has a few suggestions for a 'hard way'.

Comment: @jarnbjo : So, the only way is to remove the BOM characters ?
   No API exists for skipping this